# Definir domínio para container docker-compose

Tags: apache, domínio, docker

Estou começando a usar docker-compose e gostaria de saber como configuro um domínio para o meu container apache via docker-compose.yml? Atualmente para acessar o meu container eu digito localhost:3000.

```
cms:
  environment:
    O2_MYSQL_HOST: mysql
  TZ: "America/Sao_Paulo"
  image: o2multi/apache-php7
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "3000:80"
  volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www/html/
    - ./devops/docker/webserver/custom.ini:/etc/php/7.1/apache2/conf.d/666-custom.ini
    - ./devops/docker/webserver/o2.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-o2.conf
  links:
    - mysql
```

Comment: Fala amigo, quando você diz dominio você está dizendo que tem um dominio ".com, .com.br" comprado e gostaria de apontar para seu container ?

Comment: Não, eu apenas quero poder acessar o meu container via um domínio não comprado. Ex: docker.qqrcoisa.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer acessar por um domínio somente na sua máquina, uma forma simples é mudar a porta de 3000 para 80 no seu container e alterar o arquivos hosts adicionando o "domínio" que quer usar.

```
127.0.0.1     meu.dominio.com
```

Cadas SO mantém o mesmo em locais diferentes.

- Windows: C:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
- Linux: /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o apontamento de um container docker para um dominio específico usando Proxy Reverso.

Primeiro, você vai precisar criar um novo arquivo .conf em \etc\apache2\sites-avaiable algo tipo isso:

`meusite.com.br.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName meusite.com.br 
  ProxyPass / http://<IP_DO_SERVIDOR>:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://<IP_DO_SERVIDOR>:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

e depois habilitar e reiniciar o apache

```
$ a2ensite meusite.com.br.conf
$ service apache2 reload
```

Basicamente o que vai acontecer aqui é que toda requisição feita para esse dominio **meusite.com.br** vai ser direcionada para a porta 3000 especificada na configuração do VirtualHost.

Lembra que que se estiver usando o docker-compose de colocar a diretiva `restart: always` para que o container seja recarregado toda vez que a máquina for bootada.

Comment: O que preciso fazer para que a url seja: meusite.com.br/webapps?